# jQuery Ajax not invoking C# Webmethod

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I know multiple queries like below exist on this forum but I could not found what exactly is wrong in my case.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "default.aspx/GetMaturityValues",
    data: jsonParams,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response);
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
});
```

```csharp
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string GetMaturityValues(string countryIDList, string xAxis, string yAxis, string bubbleSize)
{
    //some code   
}
```

The execution is not flowing into C# code.

The jsonParams:

```
var paramList = '';
var countryIDList = '1,2,3,5';
var xAxis = '1';
var yAxis = '2';
var bubbleSize = '6';
paramList += 'countryIDList' + '":"' + countryIDList;
paramList += 'xAxis' + '":"' + xAxis;
paramList += 'yAxis' + '":"' + yAxis;
paramList += 'bubbleSize' + '":"' + countryIDList;
paramList = '{' + paramList + '}';
var jsonParams = JSON.stringify(paramList);
```

Comment: *Is not flowing into C# code* What exactly do you mean by that? Do you want to translate the ajax into C#?

Comment: The Ajax code is not calling the intended method.

Comment: What are you getting in failure response?

Comment: Show your `jsonParams`

Comment: No Failure response. When I try to put breakpoint on the code inside GetMaturityValue , it never hits.

Comment: Have you tried removing the parameters? Just wanted to check if that hits the WebMethod. Just to narrow down the options...

Comment: What is the error response showed in your browser debugger?

Comment: pretty sure your paramList is not valid - there are closing speechmarks (") but not opening ones for the param names, and opening ones but not closing ones for the values. And that's a crazy way to build JSON anyway - a JSON object is just a javascript one (that's one reason why JSON is so useful!), so declare it like a normal JS object and add properties. Then you can stringify the object afterwards if you need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is simply that you parameters are not correctly formatted when you post. Try this simple workaround:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var params = {};
    params.countryIDList = "test";
    params.xAxis = "x";
    params.yAxis = "y";
    params.bubbleSize = "y";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Test1.aspx/GetMaturityValues",
        data: JSON.stringify(params),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
</script>
```

@DarinDimitrov is (of course) correct that you could benefit from making a model class... But you can make it work with just sting parameters as well.

Answer (score 4):

Try using a model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public IList<int> CountryIDList { get; set; } 
    public int XAxis { get; set; }
    public int YAxis { get; set; }
    public int BubbleSize { get; set; }
}
```

that your WebMethod will take as parameter:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string GetMaturityValues(MyModel model)
{
    //some code   
}
```

and finally on the client:

```
var paramList = {
    countryIDList: [1, 2, 3, 5],
    xAxis: 1,
    yAxis: 2,
    bubbleSize: 6
};

var jsonParams = JSON.stringify({ model: paramList});

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "default.aspx/GetMaturityValues",
    data: jsonParams,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response);
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
});
```

In this example all the parameters are integers, buy you could of course use other data types like strings for example:

```
public class MyModel
{
    ...
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

which can be passes as string from the client accordingly:

```
var paramList = {
    ...
    foo: 'bar'
};
```

Comment: Needs to be `var jsonParams = JSON.stringify({ "model": paramList });` in order for parameter binding to work when using `WebMethod`

Comment: You are correct, I will update my answer to reflect your remark.